# Django Filter Model by Dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

How does one do a filter on a Django Model using a Dictionary rather than method arguments?
This is what I have right here:

```
class StoreView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request):

        # A bunch of gets
        sort = request.GET.get('sort')
        sort_price = request.GET.get('sort_price')
        sort_mfr_method = request.GET.get('mfr_method')

        # The params tpsort by
        sort_params = {}

        if sort is not None:
            sort_params['sort'] = sort

        if sort_price is not None:
            sort_params['sort_price'] = sort_price

        if sort_mfr_method is not None:
            sort_params['sort_mfr_method'] = sort_mfr_method

        # The Model Query
        design_list = models.Design.objects.filter(sort_params)

        # etc...
```

*Side Question, is there a better way set the dictionary values than what I'm doing above? Such as a ternary, yet in a way that would make the value not exist if it's none?*

```
sort_params['sort'] = sort if not None else ''
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949816/use-string-variable-kwargs-as-named-argument

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You use a dictionary to pass keyword arguments like this:

```
models.Design.objects.filter(**sort_params)
```

There's no built-in way to conditionally set a dict key, but if you do this a lot, you can write your own:

```
def set_if_not_none(mapping, key, value):
    if value is not None:
        mapping[key] = value

class StoreView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request):

        # A bunch of gets
        sort = request.GET.get('sort')
        sort_price = request.GET.get('sort_price')
        sort_mfr_method = request.GET.get('mfr_method')

        # The params tpsort by
        sort_params = {}

        set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'sort', sort)
        set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'sort_price', sort_price)
        set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'sort_mfr_method', sort_mfr_method)

        # The Model Query
        design_list = models.Design.objects.filter(**sort_params)
```

Comment: That works excellent! That makes sense because the .filter is probably defined close to: `filter(*args, **kwargs)` I just never realized you could do the above that's awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

the above answer is right and I suggest some more efficient one.

here `request.GET` is QueryDict
Just convert it into a Dictionary like this

`kwargs = dict(request.GET)`

and now filter it

`models.Design.objects.filter(**kwargs)`