# Is there a simpler way check if the filter i am filtering by is NULL in django?

Tags: django, filter, django-filter

I am wondering whether there is a simpler way to ignore NULL values when filtering in django. I don't mean NULL values in the database but rather potential NULL values I am filtering by. This is my code so far:

```
        if data['grade'] is not None:
            posts = posts.filter(grade=data['grade'])
        if data['subject'] != '':
            posts = posts.filter(subject=data['subject'])
```

Is there a way to avoid all the if clauses and write the filter in a single statement?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(grade__isnull=False) & ~Q(subject__exact=''))
```

**edit:**

you can take the idea from this here [Django Filter Model by Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018497/django-filter-model-by-dictionary)

or you can make a copy from your data

```
for i in data.copy():
        if data[i] == "" or data[i] == None:
            data.pop(i)
```

or

```
for i in data.copy():
        if not data[i]:
            data.pop(i)
```

after that `MyModel.objects.filter(**data)`

Comment: That doesn't have the same functionality, since it looks for NULL values in the database instead of NULL values in the filters.

Comment: Sorry I think you apply this condation to filter on database but in another way, you can apply only one if statement because None and ' ' is false, I will edit my answer